# why RESTapi Node working only in browser?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, http, http-headers

I recently tried to implement a nodejs api. It works very well on **localhost**, however, I went up to production using several different services, in all of them the same problem happened:

**My api returns correctly in the browser**,** but it doesn't work calling in the frontend or by postman**... I've already added all possible headers and nothing works, I suspected it was because it wasn't a secure connection (https), but even disabling it in the browser, still not working... someone help me please?

**added headers on api:**
`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"); res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"); res.header("Accept", "application/json"); res.header("Referrer-Policy","no-referrer")`

**added headers on frontend:**
`Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',`

Comment: What error message are you getting when you try to access your API from your frontend app ?

Comment: in response tab: "failed to load response data: no data found for resource with given identifier"

and in headers tab: "provisional header are shown"

and console tab:
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://191.<..rest of my ip>:3001'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Comment: This is happening because you frontend is hosted on htttps and trying to access an API that is not secure. You need to server your API over https and it will resolve the issue.